# Please help compile brogue-1.7

Tags: compiling

I downloaded sources from https://sites.google.com/site/broguegame/brogue-1.7.4-linux-amd64.tbz2?attredirects=0&d=1

unpacked them with `tar -xf ./brog*`

then tried to make and got errors about missing libsdl1.2, so I've installed it with `sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev`

then I got errors about missing `ncurses.h` and installed few packages: `sudo apt-get install ncurses-term ncurses-base ncurses-bin libncurses5-dev`

make generates long output with warnings and the error:

```
~/brogue/brogue-1.7.4$ make
./brogue: line 4: ./brogue: No such file or directory
cc -O2 -march=i586 -o bin/brogue src/brogue/Architect.o src/brogue/Combat.o src/brogue/Dijkstra.o src/brogue/Globals.o src/brogue/IO.o src/brogue/Items.o src/brogue/Light.o src/brogue/Monsters.o src/brogue/Buttons.o src/brogue/Movement.o src/brogue/Recordings.o src/brogue/RogueMain.o src/brogue/Random.o src/brogue/MainMenu.o src/brogue/Grid.o src/brogue/Time.o src/platform/main.o src/platform/platformdependent.o src/platform/curses-platform.o src/platform/tcod-platform.o src/platform/term.o -L. -Lsrc/libtcod-1.5.2 `sdl-config --cflags` `sdl-config --libs` -ltcod -Wl,-rpath,. -lncurses -lm -Wl,-rpath,.
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcod
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

again `make clean` and `make both` end up with the error:

```
cc -O2 -march=i586 -o bin/brogue src/brogue/Architect.o src/brogue/Combat.o src/brogue/Dijkstra.o src/brogue/Globals.o src/brogue/IO.o src/brogue/Items.o src/brogue/Light.o src/brogue/Monsters.o src/brogue/Buttons.o src/brogue/Movement.o src/brogue/Recordings.o src/brogue/RogueMain.o src/brogue/Random.o src/brogue/MainMenu.o src/brogue/Grid.o src/brogue/Time.o src/platform/main.o src/platform/platformdependent.o src/platform/curses-platform.o src/platform/tcod-platform.o src/platform/term.o -L. -Lsrc/libtcod-1.5.2 `sdl-config --cflags` `sdl-config --libs` -ltcod -Wl,-rpath,. -lncurses -lm -Wl,-rpath,.
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcod
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/brogue] Error 1
```

More messages for `make curses`:

```
~/brogue/brogue-1.7.4$ make curses
./brogue: line 4: ./brogue: No such file or directory
cc -O2 -march=i586 -o bin/brogue src/brogue/Architect.o src/brogue/Combat.o src/brogue/Dijkstra.o src/brogue/Globals.o src/brogue/IO.o src/brogue/Items.o src/brogue/Light.o src/brogue/Monsters.o src/brogue/Buttons.o src/brogue/Movement.o src/brogue/Recordings.o src/brogue/RogueMain.o src/brogue/Random.o src/brogue/MainMenu.o src/brogue/Grid.o src/brogue/Time.o src/platform/main.o src/platform/platformdependent.o src/platform/curses-platform.o src/platform/tcod-platform.o src/platform/term.o -lncurses -lm -Wl,-rpath,.
src/platform/tcod-platform.o: In function `loadFont':
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:36: undefined reference to `SDL_GetVideoInfo'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:56: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_set_custom_font'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:57: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_init_root'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:59: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_map_ascii_codes_to_font'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:60: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_set_keyboard_repeat'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:61: undefined reference to `TCOD_mouse_show_cursor'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:63: undefined reference to `SDL_RWFromFile'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:63: undefined reference to `SDL_LoadBMP_RW'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:63: undefined reference to `SDL_WM_SetIcon'
src/platform/tcod-platform.o: In function `gameLoop':
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:68: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:76: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_delete'
src/platform/tcod-platform.o: In function `tcod_plotChar':
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:129: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_put_char_ex'
src/platform/tcod-platform.o: In function `processSpecialKeystrokes':
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:141: undefined reference to `TCOD_sys_save_screenshot'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:147: undefined reference to `TCOD_sys_get_char_size'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:155: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_set_fullscreen'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:162: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_set_fullscreen'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:167: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_delete'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:171: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_flush'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:178: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_set_fullscreen'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:183: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_delete'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:186: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_flush'
src/platform/tcod-platform.o: In function `rewriteKey':
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:202: undefined reference to `SDL_GetModState'
src/platform/tcod-platform.o: In function `getModifiers':
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:226: undefined reference to `SDL_GetKeyState'
src/platform/tcod-platform.o: In function `tcod_pauseForMilliseconds':
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:327: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_flush'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:328: undefined reference to `TCOD_sys_sleep_milli'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:332: undefined reference to `TCOD_sys_check_for_event'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:334: undefined reference to `TCOD_sys_check_for_event'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:343: undefined reference to `TCOD_mouse_get_status'
src/platform/tcod-platform.o: In function `tcod_nextKeyOrMouseEvent':
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:366: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_flush'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:373: undefined reference to `TCOD_sys_elapsed_milli'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:375: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_is_window_closed'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:400: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_is_key_pressed'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:403: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_is_key_pressed'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:416: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_is_key_pressed'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:419: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_is_key_pressed'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:427: undefined reference to `SDL_GetAppState'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:428: undefined reference to `TCOD_sys_sleep_milli'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:434: undefined reference to `TCOD_console_flush'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:438: undefined reference to `TCOD_sys_check_for_event'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:448: undefined reference to `TCOD_mouse_get_status'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:450: undefined reference to `SDL_GetAppState'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:510: undefined reference to `TCOD_sys_elapsed_milli'
/home/billy/brogue/brogue-1.7.4/src/platform/tcod-platform.c:513: undefined reference to `TCOD_sys_sleep_milli'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/brogue] Error 1
```

Comment: Is there a `README` file in the `brogue-1.7.4` directory? Read it.

Comment: Yes, I've read it

Comment: Read all the UPPERCASE named files - `README` or `INSTALL` should tell you of the prerequsites (thing that must be installed for `brouge` to work.

Comment: I couldn't find installation requiremens. That is why I've written that post. There are `readme` and `Readme.rtf` files in the archive. Niether of them contains compilation prerequisites.

Comment: `:~/brogue/brogue-1.7.4$ ls`
`agpl.txt  bin  brogue  brogue.desktop  Brogue seed catalog.txt  Makefile  make-link-for-desktop.sh  readme  Readme.rtf  src`

Answer (score 0):

Just bumped into this - apparently Brogue is built using `libtcod` [a.k.a. "The Doryen Library"](http://roguecentral.org/doryen/libtcod/), a dedicated application framework for rougelike console games (in turn based on [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org)). `libtcod`is not available in the Ubuntu repos, so you have to build it from source or [download one of their binaries](https://github.com/libtcod/libtcod/releases). The official site can be found at https://bitbucket.org/libtcod/libtcod which provides a Mercurial repo, or, if you prefer Git head over to https://github.com/libtcod/libtcod

> libtcod is a free, fast, portable and uncomplicated API for roguelike developers providing an advanced true color console, input, and lots of other utilities frequently used in roguelikes.